# Call an action under the JQuery tab

Tags: c#, html, razor

Got couple of tabs and partial views rendering under those.

What I'd like to do is instead of just rendering the partial view but to call an action that is gonna return the view.

Something like:

```
 <li  class="active">
        <a data-modal-transform="lg" data-toggle="tab" href="#webcms-shop-home">@Lang("Home")</a>
    </li>

   <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="webcms-shop-home" style="position: relative;">

        @*@Html.Partial("~/Views/WebCMS/Shop/_ShopCms.cshtml", Model)*@ //Instead of this !

        @Url.Action("Shop", "WebCms", new { id = Model.ShopId }) //This is rendering as /WebCms/Shop/12 atm.
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`Html.RenderAction`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.childactionextensions.renderaction(v=vs.118).aspx) instead of `Url.Action`

> Invokes a child action method and renders the result inline in the parent view.

```
@{Html.RenderAction("Shop", "WebCms", new { id = Model.ShopId })}
```